# How to safely change github account name?

Tags: git, github, rename, account

I would like to change my github account name, I found an option in **GitHub** account settings.

However, I am concerned about consequences and would like to know what is the best strategy of name change, considering that I have some projects of my own tied to this account.

**So far, I came up with this plan:**

1. **Change account name in GitHub settings**
2. **For each project's local folder in '.git / config' file update *remote "origin"* url to the new one**

Will this work? Should there be any further steps on a computer which holds project sources? What will be the effect of name change on those who cloned or forked my projects on GitHub?

Thank you!

Comment: What did GitHub say when you contacted them with this support question regarding their product?

Comment: They sent this:

----------------------------------------
From: Tekkub (GitHub Staff)
Subject: Renaming user account scenario

For (2), it's best not to edit the config directly, try this: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url

Fixing URLs is the only thing you have to worry about with renaming, nothing else changes.

----------------------------------------

Which worked out just fine. The only thing - those who cloned my project locally would need to re-clone or update remotes manually

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1.) You have to change all your projects remote addresses. You can see them via:

```
git remote -v
```

After that remove the old remote addres:

```
git remote rm git@github.com:old_account/foo.git
```

finally add your new remote address:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:new_account/foo.git
```

2.) All your cloned repos will **break**. There is no URL-redirect or anything similar. You can change your local cloned repos, but others have to point to the new repo addres(like in Step 1)

Note: Github forked repos works without any problem.

Comment: Works good! Also, there is slightly different command to accomplish the same: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url

Comment: @Petros with fork I meant actually "git clone" by other people. But in Github you're right. Because all forks are have different remote origins. Thanks for the notice! I'll change it

Comment: Note: GitHub now has URL redirects for repositories from renamed users, so your clones will not break.

Answer (score 15):

GitHub has recently changed their username rename system, and now sets up redirects for you.

From [What happens when I change my username?](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-when-i-change-my-username) on GitHub Help:

> On the GitHub side, everything will behave as if your new username had
>   always been your name. All of your repositories will now belong to
>   that new name and the old username will essentially no longer exist.
>   This can take a few minutes to complete after you initiate the change.
>
> Links to your previous profile page, such as
>   https://github.com/previoususername, return a 404 error. We cannot set
>   up a redirect from the old username to the new one for references like
>   @mentions.
>
> However, redirects are setup for all your repositories. Both web and
>   git access to the old location continue to function, and redirect
>   toward the new username.

Answer (score 4):

I left a script in my ~/bin called git-reremote with the following content:

```
 #!/bin/sh
old=richoH
new=richo
git remote -v | grep $old | while read name url type; do
    newurl=`echo $url | sed -e "s/$old/$new/"`
    git remote set-url $name $newurl
done
```

It's a bit of a hack but it works nicely enough, just cd into the git repo and call `git reremote` (after making sure it's in your `$PATH` and also that you've fixed the old and new variables.