# Will changing my Github username to SnakeCase break anything?

Tags: git, github, rename, case-sensitive, account

So I read [How to safely change github account name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889436/how-to-safely-change-github-account-name)

But if I just change my username from `stevemoser` to `SteveMoser` that shouldn't break any of my repos right? Or is Git case sensitive?

Comment: Might depend more on whether your file system is case sensitive or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested it out, and it'll break cloning urls (`git://`, `ssh`) *(at least on windows*.

Although, web Urls will still work as they're case insensitive.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2017? I've tried `git clone` from Linux and it seems both mixed case and lowercase URLs work fine

Comment: I have also confirmed this in 2020. Using mixed case has worked for me, it appears everything is case insensitive.